# Exporting entire project in Visual Studio 15

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, export, projects-and-solutions

I need to send off this project I've been working on via email so I'd like to just zip up the project folder and send it off. I've done this in previous version of VS with no problem but with Visual studio 15 the project folder only contains the solution file a `.vs` folder and a `packages` folder. None of the actual files are included i.e default.aspx and so on.. If I try to zip up this folder and send it off it doesn't open on the other end. I've tried exporting as a template but that didn't really work because it doesn't contain the solution file. Is there any easy way to just export the entire project so that it can be easily opened by another user on a different computer (They need to be able to see each individual file in the solution basically how you see it in the solution explorer)?

Answer (score 0):

I use **CleanProject** for this, amazingly, it still does a fantastic job with my VS2015 projects. It cleans (removes bin/*, obj/* etc) and then creates a minimum zipfile.

You can download it here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bca632e0-3948-43c8-b337-da47275717b6

It does not work from VS2015, but from the file explorer. If that doesen't freak you out, it's a great timesaver for those situations :)